# Google Spreadsheet display live output to HTML table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, html-imports

Trying to build a connection between a Google spreadsheet and an HTML table. I also want this html page and the Google sheet to be able to be editable by one another, and to include on change events that update back and forth. I want to accomplish this using only JS/Jquery and mayyyybe using one of the available Google apis.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }
         
        table td, table th {
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          padding: 8px;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
        table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
         
        table th {
          padding-top: 12px;
          padding-bottom: 12px;
          text-align: left;
          background-color: #ff7b00;
          color: white;
        }
        </style>
</head>
 
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">User Data</h1>
    <table class="output"></table>
</body>
 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
        table {
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }
         
        table td, table th {
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          padding: 8px;
        }
        table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
        table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
         
        table th {
          padding-top: 12px;
          padding-bottom: 12px;
          text-align: left;
          background-color: #ff7b00;
          color: white;
        }
        </style>
```

JS (currently inline, attempting to avoid indexing in a database, which would defeat the purpose of eventually using a google sheet as a makeshift database):

```
<script>
const sheetId = '1SdAVVSyqpsyHzOrdfq-w7gDtqmfS8wzxsOfMmre1Guo';
const base = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${sheetId}/gviz/tq?`;
const sheetName = 'user-data';
const query = encodeURIComponent('Select *')
const url = `${base}&sheet=${sheetName}&tq=${query}`
 
const data = []
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
 
const output = document.querySelector('.output')
 
function init() {
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(rep => {
            //Remove additional text and extract only JSON:
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(rep.substring(47).slice(0, -2));
            console.log(rep)
 
            const colz = [];
            const tr = document.createElement('tr');
            //Extract column labels
            jsonData.table.cols.forEach((heading) => {
                if (heading.label) {
                    let column = heading.label;
                    colz.push(column);
                    const th = document.createElement('th');
                    th.innerText = column;
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                }
            })
            output.appendChild(tr);
 
            //extract row data:
            jsonData.table.rows.forEach((rowData) => {
                const row = {};
                colz.forEach((ele, ind) => {
                    row[ele] = (rowData.c[ind] != null) ? rowData.c[ind].v : '';
                })
                data.push(row);
            })
            processRows(data);
        })
}
  
function processRows(json) {
    json.forEach((row) => {
 
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        const keys = Object.keys(row);
     
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            const td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = row[key];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        })
        output.appendChild(tr);
    })
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Sounds cool. Do you have an actual question? About some code that you already wrote? Please take the [tour] and read through [ask].

Comment: Code included below:

Comment: Yes! I have tried to simply change the sheetID to link to a different target sheet, but I need help determining why html output won't show the new sheet's data after I reference new sheet it in const sheetId = '1SdAVVSyqpsyHzOrdfq-w7gDtqmfS8wzxsOfMmre1Guo'; wondering what I might be missing